# Altium Designer schematic opening error

Tags: altium, error, schematic

Sorry about that I am asking this question here, I had designed a schematic before in previous version of Altium Designer after fully uninstalled 20.2.7 version then I updated my Altium Designer to 22.7.1 and now when I want to open it, I am getting this error.

[image]

**PS:** after I uninstalled Altium Designer 22.7.1 and reinstalled older one I Can open scheme file, but now when I want to see footprint of a symbol I'm getting another error that is :  Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)).

After searching a lot on Google I didn't find any issues like that and related to Altium Designer.

Comment: Have you consulted the [Altium Support](https://www.altium.com/support) or [Altium Forums](https://live.altium.com/signin)? Those are the first places I'd check for an answer.

Comment: Yes, I will do, but it's like a bug and I asked here so that maybe someone had experience about it,

Comment: I'm not saying that you can't ask this question here. This just hits me as a type of question that the Manufacturer of the software can answer most reliably. And if it's a bug, they'd probably want to know. We're using Mentor PADS. When we have similar issues, Mentor responds fairly quickly with a solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks anyway.

Comment: You can have multiple versions of Altium installed at the same time, they won't interfere with each other (Altium is very proud of that).  Reinstall the older version and maybe you can open the file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes I did, and it seems ok, but I don't know maybe this problem will appear again or not and also in newer version of Altium I've got this error too.     Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Answer (score 0):

click on components(at the right corner up) then from operations choose file-based library preferences from the window select the library which contains your componet and remove it.
now recompile your integrated library
it is done